# set up one storeview for multiple domains

Tags: magento2.4, configuration, store-view, multidomain

Is there a way to create a Magento 2.4 instance, that has one website => one storeview
and this one storeview is divided depending en each functionality to multiple domains for exemple:
myacountabc.test => customer pages
mycatalogabc.test => for catalog and search pages
mycartabc.test => for checkout page and cart pages
ect
all these domains redirect to same storeview

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create a Magento 2.4 instance with one website and one store view that is divided into multiple domains for different functionalities. To achieve this, you can follow the steps below:

1. Set up your Magento 2.4 instance with one website and one store view.
2. Create the additional domains that you want to use for each functionality (e.g., myacountabc.test, mycatalogabc.test, mycartabc.test).
3. Set up your web server (e.g., Apache, Nginx) to redirect each domain to the same store view in Magento 2.4.
4. In Magento 2.4, go to Stores > Configuration > General > Web.
5. Under the Base URLs section, enter the base URL for each of your domains.
6. Under the Store View section, select your store view and set the Secure Base URL and Unsecure Base URL for each of your domains.
7. Save your changes and test each of your domains to ensure they are redirecting to the correct store view in Magento 2.4.

Note: You may also need to configure your DNS settings to point each domain to the IP address of your web server.

Comment: there is just one field to set base_url in scope storeview so in standard Magento we can have only one domain per store-view, but in my sutiation I need multiple demains which enable me to attache  each domain to a functionality  (ex : customer/account , cms ...)